# Jquery Image Preload get image height

Tags: jquery, image-preloader

I am using the image preload plugin from this page. http://www.farinspace.com/jquery-image-preload-plugin/ .

I am trying to get the height of the image with the code below.However this alerts a bunch of garbage instead of the images height.

```
$.imgpreload('myJpg.jpg',function()
    {
      alert($(this).height);
});
```

Wondering now if it is possible to dynamically get the images height?

Answer (score 0):

No need to use the image preload plugin to get the height

```
var height = $("img[src='myJpg.jpg']").height();
alert(height);
```

Comment: But I need to use the image preload plugin. I am loading a bunch of images.